# SqlBulkCopy deal with batch size in ado.net

Tags: ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have the following code to enter some data in the database using the class SqlBulkCopy from ADO.NET

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(DCISParameters.ConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbzErgoAnalytical";
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 250;
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column1", "fldESPA");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column2", "fldEP");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column13", "fldMISCode");
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dbTable);
            bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied;
        }
```

dbTable is a DataTable object that is passed as a parameter from a method and it contains 7691 rows that i take from an excel file. I have set the batch size to 250. The problem is that 7500 (250 * 30) rows are transferred correctly to the database but then i receive the following error: "Column 'fldMISCode' does not allow DBNull.Value." I am 100% sure that there is no null value in the fldMISCode and i suppose that in the last insert i have only 191 rows left which is less than the batch size (not sure if my assumption in correct). Any idea how to deal with this error? Thanks in advance...

Comment: error msg is very explicit... SELECT * FROM Source WHERE fldMISCode  IS NULL ....

Comment: I am sorry but i do not understand your answer. In fact i do not SELECT columns, i INSERT them. And the fldMISCode is never null as i explain above that is why this problem is strange to me. Thank you...

Comment: That query determines if the column is NULL. That's why I posted it!

Comment: Is there a possibility that in the last insert it tries to insert 250 rows when it has only 191 and puts all other values as null?